# hsql, JpaRepository, named parameters to string

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, hsqldb

Now I am trying

```
public interface DishRepository extends JpaRepository<Dish,Integer> {
      @Query("select d from Dish d where d.menu.date >=:startDate and d.menu.date<=:endDate")
      List<Dish> getBetween(@Param("startDate") @NotNull LocalDate startDate,
                            @Param("endDate") @NotNull LocalDate endDate);
```

and get an error since

`DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.logResult:1101 - Failed to complete request: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [2020-07-02] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2020-07-02] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (n/a)]`

but all is well if

`@Query("select d from Dish d where d.menu.date >='2020-07-02' and d.menu.date<='2020-07-03'")`

How to convert named parameters to strings `(:startDate -> '2020-07-02')` ?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use LocalDateTime as parameter. You can create LocalDateTime from LocalDate with time this way

```
LocalDateTime startOfDay = LocalDateTime.of(startDate, LocalTime.MIN);
LocalDateTime endOfDay = LocalDateTime.of(endDate, LocalTime.MAX);
```

And use them in query

```
  @Query("select d from Dish d where d.menu.date >=:startDate and d.menu.date<=:endDate")
  List<Dish> getBetween(@Param("startDate") @NotNull LocalDateTime startDate,
                        @Param("endDate") @NotNull LocalDateTime endDate);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, try to read here in your spare time https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers